# How to adjust grandparent style with only a specific child element?

Tags: html, css

I am wanting `#homeContainer` to have the full width of the page. A grandparent element is controlling the width and margin.

Below is the DOM. When I uncheck `margin: 0 auto` the full width is achieved. How can I control the `.p-body-inner` code for only code associated with `#homeContainer`?

[image]

[image]

```css
.p-body
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-height: 1px;
  background: gray;
}
.p-body-inner
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.p-body-main
{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    min-height: 1px; // IE11 workaround - related to #139187
}
#homeContainer {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 80vh;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-body">
    <div class="p-body-inner">
    <div class="p-body-main">
      <section id="homeContainer">
      Need full width of .p-body
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this generated in a server side template (or front end framework) such that you can set another class on the `p-body` for that homecontainer page? If not can add a class with javascript

Comment: Yes, this is from a CMS. I have `#homeContainer` in an HTML widget. The `p-body` class is called in from the server or at least a different file. I can call either though.

Comment: So you could do `.p-body.specialClass{ /* rule*/}` and that would be a more specific css selector and over ride the other

Comment: @charlietfl Couldn't I just do the same in the HTML widget I have? It populates after the other css file, so it should override? Is there a way to call out `#homeContainer` and `p-body-inner` together to override the margin just for the `homeContainer` section?

Comment: Something like: `document.querySelector('#homecontainer').closest('.p-body-inner').style...`? Or instead of style add the class `.closest('.p-body-inner').classList.add('specialClass')`

Comment: @charlietfl Awesome! That did the trick for that container. However, it affected everything on the page. This is the actual page. https://stangline.com/ewr-porta/ ... I ended up adding `document.querySelector('#homeContainer').closest('.p-body-inner').style.margin = '0';`

Comment: Not familiar enough to know what is expected to be honest. Also getting too late here to really dig into it

Comment: @charlietfl I am just wanting the margin for `.p-body-inner` to be changed where the section `#homeContainer` is. Then the rest of the page to be unaffected.

Comment: Simply use `box-sizing: border-box` it may or may not work. If it doesn't then let me know I will try to solve your query. Thanks.

Comment: @DragonSoup That didn't help.

Comment: okay answered you checkout it out!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use percentage instead of VW it's because 100% is the entire width of the parent element. However, 100vw is the entire width of the window. Width of the window is more than the width of the element. Hence, the child element overflows out of the parent element.

```css
.p-body
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-height: 1px;
  background: gray;
}
.p-body-inner
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.p-body-main
{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    min-height: 1px; // IE11 workaround - related to #139187
}
#homeContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-body">
    <div class="p-body-inner">
    <div class="p-body-main">
      <section id="homeContainer">
      Need full width of .p-body
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If this answer works for you then select this answer as the accepted answer to help others who checkout this question in furture.